# Remove characters from string using cmd.exe batch file and ffmpeg

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, replace, cmd

Here is the code...

```
@echo off
:: set paths (no quotes)
set ffmpeg=F:\Video\Ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe
set infolder=F:\Downloads
set outfolder=F:\Video\Finished



@echo.
@echo on
for %%f in (%infolder%\*.mp4) do "%ffmpeg%" -i "%%~dpnf.mp4" -c copy "%outfolder%\%%~nf.mp4"
@echo off
if errorlevel 1 pause
@echo.
```

This code converts an mpeg-dash file to mp4.
An mpeg-dash is a streaming file format.

The input and output file looks like this: "filename - DASH_V.mp4". (no quotes)

I would like the output file to have the " - DASH_V" removed, so it looks like "filename.mp4". (no quotes)

Any help would be appreciated. Could be a quick fix like changing "%%~dpnf~-13.0.mp4" to last command, but I am clueless on syntax as you can see.

Tried a million things and got nowhere. Clueless on syntax.

Comment: Ignoring your question, `:: set paths (no quotes)` is wrong. It, should be `Rem`, not `::` and the string is untrue. I say that because `set ffmpeg=F:\Video\Ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe`, `set infolder=F:\Downloads`, and `set outfolder=F:\Video\Finished`, should at the very least be `set "ffmpeg=F:\Video\Ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"`, `set "infolder=F:\Downloads"`, and `set "outfolder=F:\Video\Finished"`. Then `@echo on` should be `echo on`, and both instances of `@echo.`, should be `echo(`. `%infolder%\*.mp4` should be `"%infolder%\*.mp4"`, `"%%~dpnf.mp4"`, `"%%~ff"` or `"%%~dpnxf"` and `%%~nf.mp4`, `%%~nxf`.

Comment: The code you have submitted does not attempt the task you have mentioned in the body text. We are here to help with the code you have written and has in some way exhibited a problem. Please use the search facilicy to locate examples you can leverage for your own code. You said you had "Tried a million things", and we cannot guess which of those you need us to assist you with. We are not here to write code for you and it is not our responsibility to search for you, or to hand hold you through it. Once you can fulfill the [ask] guidance, feel free to [Edit] your question.

Comment: @Compo: `@echo(` isn't any better than `@echo.` (although here `echo.` would be just as good) and if reached with echo off `echo on` is no different from `@echo on`.

Comment: Okay @dave_thompson_085, I should have added that the use of the `@` prefix is completely independent of the command `echo`, _(there is no such command as `@echo`)_. Prefixing every instance of only only one command, `echo`, simply indicates that the author has no understanding of what `@` is supposed to do. As for your first statement, I ask that you read [this thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774), then perhaps consider a retraction.

Comment: Because you have received answers which either do not aswer the question, or have issues, the simplest way to perform the exact task you have laid out, and using the same type of variable substring modification, would be to replace your line ```for %%f in (%infolder%\*.mp4) do "%ffmpeg%" -i "%%~dpnf.mp4" -c copy "%outfolder%\%%~nf.mp4"```, with these four: **1.** ```For %%G In ("%infolder%\* - DASH_V.mp4") Do (Set "basename=%%~nG"```, **2.** ```SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion```, **3.** ```"%ffmpeg%" -i "%%~G" -c copy "%outfolder%\!basename:~,-9!%%~xG"```, **4.** ```EndLocal)```.

Comment: @Compo: okay; I didn't know about that failure case. (I can't imagine why anyone would _want_ a file named `echo.` but as long as something is possible someone will probably do it.) But I do sometimes `@` individual commands while developing and then later decide to `@echo off` without bothering to clean them up; it's slightly unaesthetic but absolutely well-defined and reliable.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using the `@` prefix, I use it frequently myself. That however was not the point of my comment. My comment was because many people seem to think that because it almost always prepended to `Echo Off` that it somehow is part of the `Echo` command, _(and it isn't)_. In fact the least likely place it should ever be used is before `Echo On`, _(because for that command to be used, echoing should already be off, and the prefix completely unnecessary)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that I tested. I tried to keep it close to the original.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

@echo off
:: set paths (no quotes)
set "ffmpeg=F:\Video\Ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"
set "infolder=F:\Downloads"
set "outfolder=F:\Video\Finished"

set "ffmpeg=ffmpeg.exe"


echo/
echo off
for %%E in ("%sourcedir%\*.mp4") do (
 ECHO "%%~dpnE.mp4"
 "%ffmpeg%" -i "%%~dpnE.mp4" -c copy "%destdir%\%%~nE.mp4" >NUL 2>NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL ECHO failed ON "%%~dpnE.mp4" with ERRORLEVEL %%errorlevel%%&GOTO fail
)
@echo off
if errorlevel 1 PAUSE
:fail
echo/
GOTO :EOF
```

First, I set the value of `ffmpeg` to a value that suits my system. This obviously needs to be executed after `ffmpeg` is set by the original code.

Next, I use `echo/` to `echo` a blank line. This appears to overcome the problems with `echo.` and `echo(`

I removed the unnecessary `@`s - only needed where `echo` is `on`. The `echo off` before the `for` statement is a placeholder which was originally `ON` for debugging, but I was not interested in listing the commands executed.

I changed the `metavariable` to `%%E` because I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables). ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)

The filename is now quoted as the path contains spaces.

Then I `echo`ed the filename being processed.

Then execute `ffmpeg`, but suppress the output and error-output (easier to find *my* messages that way)

Then - the test of `errorlevel` should be executed **immediately after** the `ffmpeg` as `errorlevel` will be set to the value the last time `ffmpeg` was executed, so a sequence of ...fail...pass... would leave `errorlevel` set at 0, not `1` as expected by the original code.

I found that the result generated in the destination directory was `filename.mp4` as expected, not `filename - DASH_V.mp4` as appeared to be the case on first reading.

If it is in fact the case that the conversion of "dash videos" `whatever.mp4` is creating `filename - DASH_V.mp4` as claimed, then

```
ren "%outfolder%\%%~nf - DASH_V.mp4%" "%~nf.mp4"
```

directly after the `if errorlevel 1` directly following the `ffmpeg` line should rename as desired.

I have no video files that create a file with the claimed name, so unfortunately I can't test that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly alter the filename of a `for` variable. You *can* delete (or replace) a substring in a normal CMD variable, but to use such here you need 'delayedexpansion' with `!` instead of `%`, roughly like:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (%infolder%\*.mp4) do (
  set "temp=%~nf"
  "%ffmpeg%" -i "%%~dpnf.mp4" -c copy "%outfolder%\!temp: - DASH_V=!.mp4"
  )
endlocal
```

or you can scrunch on one line with `for ... do ( set ... & "%ffmpeg" ... )`

BTW instead of `%%~dpnf.mp4` you could just use `%%f` -- the full name as found by `for`.